# Python: how to read from an XML file using the open method

Tags: python, xml

I'm trying to learn how to read and write from XML files.

The writing part is going without a problem, but when I read the file, I only get the tags and not the actual values. I get `None` as value back.

Here's my code for both the read and write part to get a full picture, but my problem is only with the write part:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
results = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,0,11,23,123123123,12223,123,1223,1223,123,123]
results_element = ET.Element("results")
for row in results:
  value= ET.SubElement(results_element, "value")
  value.text = str(row)
  xml_string= ET.tostring(results_element, encoding="unicode")

with open("results.xml", "w") as xml_file:
    xml_file.write(xml_string)

with open("results.xml", "r") as xml_file:
  s_xml_string = xml_file.read()
  s_results_element = ET.fromstring(s_xml_string)
  for target_list in s_results_element:
    my_list.append(int(target_list.find("value").text))
```

I'm getting the error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to change this line

```
my_list.append(int(target_list.find("value").text))
```

to this:

```
my_list.append(int(target_list.text))
```

The error tells you that `target_list.find` is returning `None`, which has no attribute 'text' and that's correct because you're already looping over the `<value>`.

Hope that helps

Comment: Yes, that did it. Thanks a lot for your help!